# PHP not loading php.ini in directory or following error_reporting() on Windows 7

Tags: php, windows-7, php5, apache-2.2

Normally I develop under `E_ALL` error level, but for sanity on this project I want notices and strict off. So initially tried:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~(E_STRICT|E_NOTICE));
```

And several other combinations of the same thing, nothing worked.

Next I tried to create a local php.ini the directory with `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` but nope, that didn't work either. `phpinfo()` is reporting: `Scan this dir for additional .ini files: (none)`

Can someone help me fix either of these problems? Preferably both! Thanks!

I'm running PHP Version 5.2.13 on Apache/2.2.14 under Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 1):

The usually location of php.ini is the same folder where you extract php files (c:\php). Read the [php manual intstallation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.manual.php).
Search all php.ini on server disk.

Anoher usefull read is [this](http://www.askapache.com/php/custom-phpini-tips-and-tricks.html#menu0-el7).